# Transfer mvc4 website to asp.net server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am relative new to mvc4 and i have some problems with transferring my mvc4 website made in visual studio to my asp.net host. When i move all files through the publish method, he wont show the web page. He just show text files. When i run my Global.asax file, i got the following error:

> Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.ColumnModel' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>
> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.ColumnModel' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Type:type_is_assignable_from (System.Type,System.Type)
>     at System.Type.IsAssignableFrom (System.Type c) [0x00096] in /usr/src/mono-2.10.4/mcs/class/corlib/System/Type.cs:885 
>     at System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.IsAreaRegistrationType (System.Type type) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil+<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0 (System.Type type) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Linq.Enumerable+c__Iterator35`1[System.Type].MoveNext () [0x00059] in /usr/src/mono-2.10.4/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs:3010 
>     at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Type].AddEnumerable (IEnumerable`1 enumerable) [0x0001a] in /usr/src/mono-2.10.4/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:126 
>     at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Type]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 collection) [0x0002f] in /usr/src/mono-2.10.4/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:63 
>     at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[Type] (IEnumerable`1 source) [0x00006] in /usr/src/mono-2.10.4/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs:2847 
>     at System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil.GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies (System.String cacheName, System.Predicate`1 predicate, IBuildManager buildManager) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas (System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes, IBuildManager buildManager, System.Object state) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas (System.Object state) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at HeerlijkHulp.MvcApplication.Application_Start () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
>     at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x000d5] in /usr/src/mono-2.10.4/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:226

Comment: Elaborate more about how you published the app. Also check that IIS has the same .net version you are running registered

Comment: Where or how can i check what version is installed on my hosting? How i publish:Build > Publish website > Configure ftp settings > Publish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved:
- My host didn't support MVC4